# Why are elements of Array in this case optional?

Tags: swift

```
let x = Array(repeating: "test", count: 3)
x.first.count
```

I've got an error:
"Value of optional type 'String?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'count' of wrapped base type 'String'"

Why should I write:  `x.first?.count` ?
I'm pretty sure that the first element of this array is not nil

Comment: You are sure, but the compiler isn’t.

Comment: Also, the optionality is not about the potential for the first element to be `nil`, it's about the potential for the array to be empty (thus, no first element at all). If an element can be optional (e.g. `[String?]`), then `first` actually returns a double optional (`String??`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm pretty sure that the first element of this array is not nil

Yes but it's implementation doesn't know that , it's written also in case no values exist so optional comes to rescue

```
extension Array { 
   @inlinable public var first: Element? { get }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you said, **You** are the one who is sure the first element is not `nil`. So **You** are the one who should force the compiler to unwrapped it!

The only thing compiler knows is that maybe the array will be empty like: `[]`, and there where no elements in it, So it returns optional even if you sure.

So if you are really sure, just force unwrap it:

```
x.first!.count
```

Comment: Or `x[0].count`